About the tags SHA-3 and Keccak?
Could someone explain the difference between the tags sha-3 and keccak with one example?

Keccak is pre-SHA-3 and it was evolving during the process and finalized by NIST 1  and 2

Keccak is an algorithm (a public permutation). SHA-3 is a set of standardizations for Keccak parameters and determines how it can form a sponge function which makes the core of SHA-3.

Agreed. I would probably still tag something [tag:keccak] and [tag:sponge] when talking about a specific construct that uses the Keccak sponge and is not SHA-3-224/256/384/512.
